# How can I render option field from other database table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Responsibility` with has one text field of responsibility. Other model is `Stage`, in `Stage` form field there is a `text_field` `responsibility` I want to render an option list from `responsibilities` table how can i do that in rails?

routes.rb

```rb
  resources :projects do
    resources :responsibilities
    resources :stages
  end
```

stage _form.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_with(model: stage, url: [@project, stage], local: true) do |form| %>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :responsibility, :class=>"required" %>
    <%= form.text_field :responsibility %>
  </div>


  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

How can I render responsibilities list as an option in stage responsibility form field?

what is tried is:

stage _form.html.erb

```rb
  <div>
    <%= form.label :responsibility %>
    <%= select_tag "colors", @responsibilities , multiple: true %>
  </div>
```

stages_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @stage = Stage.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @responsibilities = @project.responsibilities
  end
```

I was able to render form but in responsibility field none of the responsibility was accessed as option.

Comment: I checked your select_tag is already correct, now the questions is whether @ project has content and whether @ project.responsibilities has content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`select_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) accepts as a second parameter string that contains options as a string.
Rails provides some helper methods that are useful for generation of those `<option>`
tags

[options_from_collection_for_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), [options_for_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

If you inspect with your browser's developer tools the html code of the `<select>` tag you will see something like this:

```
<select name="colors[]" id="colors" multiple="multiple">
#&lt;Responsibility::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f3f72cc7eb0&gt;
</select>
```

This is because select_tag calls `to_s` method of `@responsibilities` collection.

The correct way of creating `select_tag` would looks something like this:

```
<%= select_tag "colors", options_from_collection_for_select(@responsibilities, :id, :name) , multiple: true %>
```

There is another way to build select field using the FormBuilder method [collection_select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select). It might look something like this:

```
  <div>
    <%= form.label :responsibility %>
    <%= form.collection_select :responsibility, @responsibilities, :id, :name, prompt: true %>
  </div>
```

I hope this answer will be useful.

Comment: Great answer, noticed one small syntax error, missing comma after `@responsibilities`:

`<%= select_tag "colors", options_from_collection_for_select(@responsibilities, :id, :name) , multiple: true %>`